# How many poker hands have exactly one pair?

Tags: combinations

I know the answer is $C_{13}^4 \times C_4^1 \times C_4^2 \times C_4^1 \times C_4^1 \times C_4^1$. But what I did was $C_{13}^1 \times C_4^2 \times C_{48}^3$.
I don't understand why we need to choose the suits for the remaining $3$ cards.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation does not avoid the mishap that the hand has two pairs or a full house.

Comment: If then,why not:C(13,1)C(4,2)C(12,1)C(4,1)C(11,1)C(4,1)C(10,1)C(4,1)?